# Mercurial color extension in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, mercurial, dvcs

Is there a way to enable color support for Mercurial in Powershell on Windows 7?  The [ColorExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ColorExtension) page says to add

```
[color]
mode = win32
```

to your `.hgrc` file, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Running `hg status` shows several files that have not yet been added to the repository, and I believe they should have a pink color (based off other terminals I've seen).  This is what's displayed instead:

```
←[0;35;1;4m? samplefile.php←[0m
←[0;35;1;4m? anotherfile.php←[0m
←[0;35;1;4m? derpderp.xml←[0m
←[0;35;1;4m? derp_model.php←[0m
←[0;35;1;4m? stillnocolor.php←[0m
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably need to update to the latest mercurial (1.6.4).  Version 1.5.4 in particular didn't do win32 color properly (and there have been quite a few color-related and win32-related bugs fixed in recent builds).

You also need to make sure you're not specifying ANSI color mode. You can force win32:

```
[color]
mode = win32
```

Comment: Nice catch, I hadn't realized I was running an older version.

Comment: Does not work in Mercurial 2.8. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Did you also make sure to enable the ColorExtension?  You need this in your .hgrc too:

```
[extensions]
color =
```

If that's there too you can make sure your settings are being picked up with:

```
hg --debug showconfig
```

Comment: Yes, the extension is enabled.  Settings show up just fine, so I'm not sure why they aren't being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`ColorExtension` does not work in PowerShell as of version 2.8, see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2013-November/054620.html:

> When using Windows PowerShell color doesn't work (although it works perfectly fine with `cmd.exe`).
>
> Looks like although being called, `_kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute` has no effect when running within PowerShell.

This is [Mercurial bug 4093](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4093) which has been resolved as "won't fix". One workaround is to use [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/). See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/85058/powershell-not-displaying-unix-colors) answer for more information.

Comment: See also https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/issues/13 and ... for goodness sakes, use ConEmu (which has ANSI support) http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/